# Extract Content from a Pseudo Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-element

Goal is to extract the text "Filter A" from the following ComputedStyle ...

```
    console.log(filters[0]);
    <td class="name" id="l:rcmrow0">
        ::before
        "Filter A"
    </td>
//
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(filters[0], ':before').getPropertyValue('content'));
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(filters[0], ':before').content);
//
var styles = getComputedStyle(filters[0], ':before');
console.log(styles.getPropertyValue('content'));
console.log(styles['content']);
```

All console.log outputs display "[]".

Please offer guidance on how to extract the pseudo element's text content.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible.

Comment: There may be some confusion - if what you show as being in the td element is a direct copy of what you are seeing in your browser's devtools inspect facility then the Filter A text is not in the content property of the before pseudo element but it's the actual text held in the td element. Try document.getElementById('l:rcmrow0').innerHTML